# photo transfer from ipad 2 to windows xp laptop

Tags: ipad

how can i transfer photos from iPad 2 to Windows XP laptop?
I tried all searches related to my problem but no use.
None of the windows office can connect to ipad 2 and the ipad 2 does not trust on windows xp

Answer (score 1):

In old days to share with others (before the synchronization age) you used places like photo share, photo boot, dropbox, google drive and so on.

You would upload your photos to one of those places then access from Windows XP and download them.